# Substitute jQuery ajax error response with a 'null object'

Tags: jquery, error-handling, jquery-deferred

Suppose the following:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: '/this/one/is/critical'
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: '/can/live/without'
    }) // recoverable failure
).done(function (getCriticalData, getOptionalData) {
    console.log('we are done.');
}).fail(function () {
    console.error('it cannot be done!');
});
```

As-is, if either call fails the `.fail` handler will fire. What I want is to (in a syntactically elegant way) configure the second ajax call to substitute error responses with a null object (e.g. `{}` or `[]`).

I could replace `.done` handler with `.always` but that requires parsing each array of parameters (`getCriticalData` and `getOptionalData`) individually (which can get ugly with n > 2). I'm looking for a boolean state - did all critical requests succeed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "catch" the second ajax's error and ensure the error handler propagates the desired recovery value down the promise chain.

Unlike in some other promise libs, jQuery promises don't have a `.catch()` method, but what you want is still syntactically very simple. Instead of `$.ajax(...).catch()`, jQuery's pattern is `$.ajax(...).then(null, errorHandler)`, in which `errorHandler` returns a promise resolved with the desired recovery value.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: '/this/one/is/critical'
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: '/can/live/without'
    }).then(null, function() { 
        return $.when([]); // return a new promise resolved with a recovery value.
    })
).done(function (getCriticalData, getOptionalData) {
    console.log('we are done.');
}).fail(function () {
    console.error('it cannot be done!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I initially tried registering on the second query a `.fail` handler that returned a value (which didn't work). It's not obvious that handlers registered via `.then` are treated differently than via `.done` and `.fail`.

Comment: @Serguei, yes exactly so! `.then()` possesses "filtering power" that `.done()` and `.fail()` lack. You can return whatever you like from `.done()` and `.fail()` and it will make no difference to what is passed down the chain.